# C# ListBox displays wrong format when used with ListViewItem

Tags: c#, listbox, listviewitem

This is my code to populate a `ListBox` named **delBooks** with a `ListViewItem` object and items `.Text` and `.Tag` properties.

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
item.Text = "ss"; // Or whatever display text you need
item.Tag = "dd";
delBooks.Items.Add(item);
```

The output I see in the `ListBox` looks like this:

`ListViewItem: {ss}`

How can I correct this so it will display `ss` in the `ListBox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object like `ListViewItem` does not exist for `ListBox`. This is one of the reasons that the `ListBox` control was superseded  by the `ListView` control. In order to get `ListViewItem` like functionality out of a `ListBox` control you must implement your own object

```
class ListBoxItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; }

    public ListBoxItem(string text, string tag)
    {
        this.Text = text;
        this.Tag = tag;
    }
}
```

To populate the `ListBox` with your custom object simply do:

```
listbox.DisplayMember = "Text";
listbox.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem("ss", "dd"));
```

Where the `.DisplayMember` property of `ListBox` is the name of the property of your custom object that is to be displayed in the `ListBox` to the user.

If you need to access your custom objects values based on your `ListBox` item collection you can do a simple cast to retrieve the these values:

```
MessageBox.Show( ((ListBoxItem)listbox.Items[0]).Tag) );
```

Where the `.Tag` property is the value `"dd"` that we set earlier

**PS:** If you're a stickler for design like I am this method will also work with a `struct`

EDIT: If you are truly dead set on using `ListViewItem` you technically can just by setting the `.DisplayMember` to (in your case) the `.Text` property of the `ListViewItem` object

Answer (score 2):

Set the `DisplayMember` on the `ListBox` to `Text` (as a string).

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your last line like "delBooks.Items.Add(item.Text.toString());"

Comment: hmm then tag will not be saved and whole purpose of using ListViewItem is lost. PS: in case what you are saying it should be just "item.Text" since it is already string

Comment: Yeah yeah it could be without toString you can do without it ı just write for explain you that add() method's arguments is string

Comment: user6095732 is right.  The Add() method of the ListBox.ObjectCollection class only takes an Object instance; there is no overload that takes a ListBoxItem instance specifically.  Whatever Object instance you stuff in has its ToString() method called to show to the user.

I think you're confusing the ListBox class with the ListView class, which is fancier.